# Change value of dynamically generated HTML with jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a dropdown menu that looks like this:

```
<?php

while($set_va = mysqli_fetch_array($get_va)) {

?>
<div class="main-assign">
    <div class="assign-va" data-bs-toggle="dropdown">
        <div class="assign-btn">
            <button type="button" class="btn dropdown-toggle dropdown-toggle-btn">
                <div class='avatar-img-left'>
                    <img src='<?= ($set_va['picture'] == NULL) ? 'uploads/emp_dp/koala.png' : 'uploads/emp_dp/'.$set_va['picture'] ?>' 
                    class='me-2 rounded-circle avatar avatar-lg set-img'>
                </div>
                <div class='avatar-text-right' style="margin-top: 0">
                    <p class='avatar-name set-name' style="text-align: left">
                        <?= (empty($set_va) ? 'Unassigned' : $set_va['name']) ?>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="assign-caret">
            <span>&#9660;</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown-menu">
        <div class="parent-employee">
            <?php while($set_emp = mysqli_fetch_array($get_emp)) { ?>

            <div class="employees" style="cursor: pointer">
                <div class='avatar-img-left'>
                    <img src='<?= ($set_emp['picture'] == NULL) ? 'uploads/emp_dp/koala.png' : 'uploads/emp_dp/'.$set_emp['picture'] ?>' 
                    class='me-2 rounded-circle avatar avatar-lg get-img' 
                    data-eimg="<?= ($set_emp['picture'] == NULL) ? 'uploads/emp_dp/koala.png' : 'uploads/emp_dp/'.$set_emp['picture'] ?>">
                </div>
                <div class='avatar-text-right'>
                    <p class='avatar-name get-name' 
                    data-ename="<?= $set_emp['name'] ?>">
                        <?= $set_emp['name'] ?>
                    </p>
                    <input type="hidden" name="mydata" class="mydata" value="" 
                    data-evalues="<?= $set_emp['id'].'#'.$set_task['id'] ?>">
                    
                    <input type="hidden" class="empid" id="empid" 
                    value="<?= $set_emp['id'] ?>">
                    <span class='avatar-desig'><?= $set_emp['designation'] ?></span>
                </div>
            </div>

            <?php } ?>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<?php } ?>
```

I want to change the image in the `set-image` class and the name in the `set-name` class with whatever options the user selects from the dropdown menu.

This is my jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $(document).on('click', '.employees', function() {
        var img = $(this).find('.get-img').data('eimg');
        var name = $(this).find('.get-name').data('ename');
        var data = $(this).find('.mydata').data('evalues');

        $('.mydata').val(data);

        $('.set-img').attr('src', img);
        $('.set-name').text(name);
    });
});
```

Now, the problem is that, as you can see that the dropdown row `main-assign` itself is being generated using PHP from a MySQL table and when I am selecting a value from the dropdown menu `dropdown-menu`, all of the rows of the on the `main-assign` are getting changed.

I am not sure how to solve this problem. Any help would be highly appreciated!

Thanks so much!

Comment: just a few notes: 1: .ready() isn't needed in your case. document is immediately ready for events being bound to it. 2: use .attr instead of .data if you don't need the additional data parsing that .data provides. (it appears as though you're just storing strings)

Comment: You noted: "as you can see that the dropdown row main-assign itself is being generated using PHP from a MySQL table and when I am selecting a value from the dropdown menu dropdown-menu, all of the rows of the on the main-assign are getting changed." What do you mean by this? you don't appear to have any logic that would cause changing the dropdown to do anything, and even if you did, you haven't really explained why this is relevant? What exactly is the problem you are facing?

Comment: The fact that PHP has generated the HTML is ultimately irrelevant to how the JS behaves - all the JS sees is what HTML you've sent to the browser. So the way to simplify and work on this problem is to ignore the PHP for a while, save the generated HTML, and create a [mre] of the JS behaviour. Then you can work out (or ask about) how you would manually change the HTML and/or JS to fix things, and feed those changes back into the full PHP version later.

Comment: I have a table that has multiple rows of "tasks". In every row, there is a dropdown that is basically used to assign employees to that particular task. What I want to achieve is that, when I am clicking on the assign employee dropdown on say task # 5, the dropdown should reflect the changes in real-time in the dropdown menu (like select option), and when I click on the assign button, there is an Ajax script that basically updates the value of assigned employee using PHP/MySQL. I hope this makes sense.